# Query table with select all, but concatenate two columns

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I am trying to query a list of customers, but on the display have their first and last names concatenated. Pretty new to Mysql sorry. I'm not sure how to go about doing this other than individually calling each attribute in the select.

So far what I've got is

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(CUS_FNAME, ' ', CUS_LNAME) AS NAME
FROM customers;
```

But of course that just appends a new column at the end with the concatenated name.

Comment: You have to list out your column names manually if you want to control what gets returned.

Comment: If thats the case then thats fine. Thank you for the reply. Just didn't want to do that if there's a more concise way of writing the query.